# Plot RGB raster on basemap in R

Tags: raster, r, rgb

I want to plot my RGB raster on a basemap in R.

So far I have a RasterStack object and I have downloaded the basemap with ggmap. I can plot them individually but not together.

```
stack_rrs <- stack(red4, green3, blue2)
plotRGB(stack_rrs,r=1,g=2,b=3, stretch = "lin")
bm <- ggmap(get_map(location = "Location", maptype = "satellite"))
```

Comment: Does `inset_raster(stack_rrs, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, interpolate = TRUE)` work?

Comment: In case a interactive map is fine, you can use `mapview::viewRGB`

Comment: when I use inset_raster, i get this error: Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

Comment: @TimSalabim I have the same issue, have you found any solution?